# Python updating histogram with random generate integers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and want to develop a histogram that update a list of 20 random integers from 0-10; but the histogram's bars don't match x-axis's value and only have 10 bars. while there are also some other bars appear in the background constantly other than the updating blue bars. What seem to be the issue? Thanks!

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
stat_num =20
range_num=10
y_lim=10

def animate(frameno):
    x = [random.randint(0, range_num) for _ in range(stat_num)]
    n, bins, ignored = plt.hist(x,stat_num)
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_ylim([0,y_lim])
    for rect, h in zip(patches, n):
        rect.set_height(h)
    return patches    


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [random.randint(0, range_num) for _ in range(stat_num)]
print(x)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x,stat_num)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0,y_lim])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=100,
                          repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to refresh the plot, add the line plt.clf() before the axes = plt.gca() in your animate function -- may not be the best approach but you get a new histogram each time!

Comment: @Robert Milletich Hi thanks for replying! I tried addind plt.clf() and this time it only shows s blank figure

Comment: Hmm...that's interesting. I placed the plt.clf() call after the n, bins, ignored = plt.hist(x,stat_num) call. It essentially clears you current figure window and allows you to redraw on the figure. Again, not the best approach but that's weird it doesn't work on your computer. If nobody else responds I'll try and figure out a better approach after work

Comment: @RobertMilletich ok Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to fix the bins yourself, via the option `bins=np.linspace(0, 10, 11)` that will use equispaced integer bins.
2. A single `plt.hist` command is enough. You can update then the existing graphic using NumPy's histogram command.

I tested the following:

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

stat_num =20
range_num=10
y_lim=10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [random.randint(0, range_num) for _ in range(stat_num)]

print(x)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=np.linspace(0, 10, 11))

def animate(frameno):
    x = [random.randint(0, range_num) for _ in range(stat_num)]
    n, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=np.linspace(0, 10, 11))
    for rect, h in zip(patches, n):
        rect.set_height(h)
    return patches

axes = plt.gca()

axes.set_ylim([0,y_lim])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=100,
                              repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! I tested the code and have following questions: I got some blue bars other than the updating bars that appears constantly; I was testing it on Mac OS

Comment: With the program above, I have a single set of bars (exactly ten bars) whose height varies as the loop runs. Maybe there is a lag effect on your computer display? You can check by using an interval of 1000 for instance.

Comment: Hmmm I still got the similar result as the image from OP. Will try a different computer